# MVC REST WebAPI and OAuth/OpenID And High Volume Requests

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, oauth, asp.net-web-api

I am looking into some technologies on how to achieve a certain result. I am new to OAuth and whatever technologies I will/should be using, so please bear with me.

I have an idea that I would like to try out: I am wanting to make a tracking app that will run on various mobile devices. It will send your location to a server that will allow you friends to know where you are on a long journey (such as across a country). My idea is that the user will allow some (a select few) of his friends to log into a web site or app and see where he is. Also, if the server detects that the user has stopped for a long time, or doing something weird, the server will notify those friends and then they can give him a call to check up. (Inspired by a colleague who went on a lone 9 hour drive across country to surprise visit his girlfriend).

Also, as part of the challenge, I want to only use Microsoft technologies such as Azure, Web API, Service Bus and ACS. I also only want to use the default ASP.NET membership providers and things - I don't want to write lots of custom code. This project is going to be an all default Microsoft code using their provided extension points for my app.

My idea also needs to interact with the other providers, such as Facebook and Google. I thought of how I could implement this by allowing the users to log in to the app to create an account with his Facebook and set up for the trip. He would then login from his device with that same Facebook account and then the app would interact with my service with a REST API. I don't want to be responsible for tracking usernames and passwords (hopefully I can use the default ASP.NET memberships and roles).

But, I have no idea at what I should be looking at. I am assuming if users are going to be sending their location every minute or so, there will be a very high volume of requests to my API. I thought of using a Queue for this, the API will just forward all locations to the Queue which would be processed by a worker. The API will be providing both a way to send the location as well as to create and modify user settings. I am unsure of the best ways to go about this. **Will a high volume of requests to my API result in a negative performance for the other requests? Should I have a separate server that handles the locations and another for the basic user management?**

Lets say I have a great uptake of this app, I don't want to have thousands of requests to the Facebook server for each location received. Is OAuth not going to work here? **Can my app cache a key that can be used with the one that the user has when he logs in via the web interface?** I want the system to be able to reject spam requests, such as a random token or something, before even reaching the queue. Is OAuth a viable means for this app?

I am unsure as this is very new to me. **How do I go about creating a high volume REST based application that uses third party authentication?** I am hoping to use plain HTTP (just because I am sure that it should be possible - and maybe someone can comment on the option of a greater overhead?) for the location updates, so I don't want the password in the message a all. Should I be using REST at all?

I know this is a long question and very broad, but I want to learn and am willing to do so, whatever it takes. Please take time to read and point out anything, good or bad.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your application design you might be interested in SignalR (http://signalr.net/). It is ideal for subscribing to requests (a bunch of friends) and then broadcasting any changes (something weird like you say) to those friends.

Microsoft is making that part of the ASP.NET platform, so it is based on Microsoft technologies: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-034

I think it is that video, or another they mention that SignalR (because of its Async nature/using WebSockets first) can scale to 20,000 messages/second on a laptop.  Authentication for this type of stuff is secondary, look at your core technology first.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will be having a look at this.